# Unwanted text inside char array

Tags: c, memory-leaks, c-strings

I am trying to "hard code" a very small JSON parser in C for a little project and I am encountering two main problems : 
The string output contain some unwanted text that came from nowhere (      actually it's description from the man page of getaddrinfo(), and I have no idea how it got there). This is the output I get :

```
    3484.  The default is:
#
#precedence  ::1/128       50
#precedence  ::/0          40
#precedence  2002::/16     30
#precedence ::/96          20
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10
#
#    For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
#
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100

#
# scopev4  <mask>  <value>
#    Add another rule to the RFC 6724 scope table for IPv4 addresses.
#    By default the scope IDs described in section 3.2 in RFC 6724 are
#    used.  Changing these defaults should hardly ever be necessary.
#    The defaults are equivalent to:
#
#scopev4 ::ffff:169.254.0.0/112  2
#scopev4 ::ffff:127.0.0.0/104    2
#scopev4 ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96       14
{id_src:103,accel_x:101,accel_y:114,accel_z:116,temp:101} <-- This is the only
wanted section !
```

The second problem I am getting is that when I try to parse two structures into a json, well, the json is kind of appending the two structures :

```
 ... The usual unwanted data before
{id_src:103,accel_x:101,accel_y:114,accel_z:116,temp:101}{$­ûrc:1id_src:103,accel_x:101,accel_y:114,accel_z:116,temp:101}
```

I tried reducing the allocated space and turned out to have an error on the free() since the char array allocated had it's size changed. This is also a weird behavior I don't really understand.

Here is the code :

```
... some code here
char* jsonData = malloc(1048*sizeof(char));
    strcat(jsonData,"{");
    char* champsTab[] = {"id_src","accel_x","accel_y","accel_z","temp"};
    char* buff=malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        strcat(buff,champsTab[i]);
        char* data=malloc(4*sizeof(char));
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                sprintf(data,":%d,",capteurs->id_src);
                strcat(buff,data);
                break;
            case 1:
                sprintf(data,":%d,",capteurs->accel_x);
                strcat(buff,data);
                break;
            case 2:
                sprintf(data,":%d,",capteurs->accel_y);
                strcat(buff,data);
                break;
            case 3:
                sprintf(data,":%d,",capteurs->accel_z);
                strcat(buff,data);
                break;
            case 4:
                sprintf(data,":%d",capteurs->temp);
                strcat(buff,data);
                break;

        }
        free(data);

    }
    strcat(jsonData,buff);
    strcat(jsonData,"}");

    printf("%s\n",jsonData);
    free(jsonData);
    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely these two lines:

```
char* jsonData = malloc(1048*sizeof(char));
strcat(jsonData,"{");
```

When you allocate memory with `malloc`, it will be uninitialized. The contents will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random. Therefore it's a large chance that the string terminator that `strcat` looks for to find the end will not be the first element in the memory. It might not even be in the allocated memory at all.

There's a simple solution to this: Use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`:

```
strcpy(jsonData,"{");
```

You have the very same problem later with `buff`.

Comment: Adding to the above comment.
You can memzero your buffer after the allocation to ensure that it's "free of garbage"

Comment: Stupid error again! strcpy solved it all ! Thanks for the reply !

Comment: @AviZana Or use `calloc`. But it's not needed if the OP use `strcpy`.